# ol.animate functions missing from Openlayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-3

I am currently developing an application using openlayers 3, attempting to apply some animation hence the use of ol.animate object, however it is missing evidently by the screenshot attached.

**ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'pan' of undefined**

**ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'bounce' of undefined**

**./Package.json**
- "openlayers": "^4.0.1"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation/release notes here:
https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/releases/tag/v4.0.0
Removal of deprecated methods
Animation methods now reside in ol.view object, hence view.animate()